# How can I set SELinux permissions from Java?

Tags: java, clojure, selinux

I want to create a file with SELinux type `svirt_sandbox_file_t`.

I believe I am looking for a [FileAttribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/FileAttribute.html) that I can pass to [createFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createFile-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-).

My target language is Clojure if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I don't think you can do this via Java NIO file attributes.  It is not supported, AFAIK.

There are two approaches I can think of:

- The most practical one is to use `Process` to run an external SELinux command to adjust the SELinux attributes after the file has been created.  I can see no reason why this wouldn't work ... assuming that your application has the required permissions to do this.
- A somewhat more difficult approach would be to use JNI to call the relevant SELinux native code libraries.  For example, I came across this class in the Android libraries: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/SELinux.java ... which appears to work that way.  I imagine this approach would work with regular Java on a regular Linux platform.